# paypal subscripition

Tags: php, paypal-subscriptions

In my site I want to integrate a paypal subscription method in which I want to transfer a particular amount from a user's paypal account to an admin's paypal account daily, weekly or monthly depending on the choice. For that i use the below code:

```
$obj=new paypal_recurring;

$obj->environment = 'sandbox';  // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'
$obj->paymentType = urlencode('Authorization');             // or 'Sale' or 'Order'

// Set request-specific fields.
$obj->startDate = urlencode("2011-9-6T0:0:0");
$obj->billingPeriod = urlencode("Month");               // or "Day", "Week", "SemiMonth", "Year"
$obj->billingFreq = urlencode("4");                     // combination of this and billingPeriod must be at most a year
$obj->paymentAmount = urlencode('10');
$obj->currencyID = urlencode('USD');                            // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

/* PAYPAL API  DETAILS */
$obj->API_UserName = urlencode('sdfsdfsdfbiz_api1.website.us');
$obj->API_Password = urlencode('543564353');
$obj->API_Signature = urlencode('sdfsdfsdf ');
$obj->API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";

/*SET SUCCESS AND FAIL URL*/
$obj->returnURL = urlencode("http://www.mysite.com/index.php?task=getExpressCheckout");
$obj->cancelURL = urlencode('http://www.mysite.comindex.php?task=error');


$task="setExpressCheckout"; //set initial task as Express Checkout

switch($task)
{
    case "setExpressCheckout":
    $obj->setExpressCheckout();
    exit;
    case "getExpressCheckout":
    $obj->getExpressCheckout();
    exit;
    case "error":
    echo "setExpress checkout failed";
    exit;
}
```

But in this code how can i add the admin's paypal email id so that i can transfer funds to that account?

Comment: Not familiar with that code, or with the PayPal API in general, but I am going to guess that it maps that on the PayPal side.  The API_* variables will connect the request to your account, and then PayPal will find the email address for that accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an account with paypal,sign up for the API keys, and then the money would go to your account.  You can't transfer it to an arbitrary account.